# Code analysis says Inconsistent annotation for 'wWinMain' : this instance has no annotations

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, annotations

I'm writing some simple win32 stuff and I'm using the following wWinMain

```cpp
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
```

VS2012 express code analysis says

> C28251    Inconsistent annotation for function: this instance has an error    Inconsistent annotation for 'wWinMain': this instance has no annotations. See c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\8.0\include\um\winbase.h(2201).   LeesSpaceShip   main.cpp    6

I'm not clear on what an annotation even is.  So what is an annotation and which part is wrong on my code?

Apart from this diagnostic the code compiles and runs just fine.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The declaration of `wWinMain` in winbase.h (mentioned in the error) is:

```
wWinMain(
    _In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int nShowCmd
    );
```

Your implementation of `wWinMain` in main.cpp is missing the [SAL annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182032.aspx) and Code Analysis is warning you about the mismatch.

Comment: So, I should do something to solve it or simply ignore it?

Comment: Can we disable the annotation analyser - seems like a pretty ridiculous requirement.